# Randomly get index of one of the maximum values in a PyTorch tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I need to perform something similar to the built-in torch.argmax() function on a one-dimensional tensor, but instead of picking the index of the first of the maximum values, I want to be able to pick a random index of one of the maximum values. For example:

```
my_tensor = torch.tensor([0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1])
index_1 = random_max_val_index_fn(my_tensor)
index_2 = random_max_val_index_fn(my_tensor)

print(f"{index_1}, {index_2}")
> 5, 1
```

Comment: One aspect you'll have to handle will be maximum values that are almost but not quite equal due to rounding errors

Comment: @sabik for my purposes, that kind of precision isn't necessary.

Comment: I mean, for most purposes, there's no point randomly picking a maximum, because there will only be one; randomly picking argmax out of `[0.1 + 0.2, 0.3]` will always give index 0, because `0.1 + 0.2 > 0.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the indexes of all the maximums first and then choose randomly from them:

```
def rand_argmax(tens):
    max_inds, = torch.where(tens == tens.max())
    return np.random.choice(max_inds)
```

sample runs:

```
>>> my_tensor = torch.tensor([0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1])
>>> rand_argmax(my_tensor)
2
>>> rand_argmax(my_tensor)
5
>>> rand_argmax(my_tensor)
2
>>> rand_argmax(my_tensor)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

your_tensor = torch.tensor([0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1])
argmaxes = np.argwhere(your_tensor==torch.max(your_tensor)).flatten()
rand_argmax = np.random.choice(argmaxes)
print(rand_argmax)
```

make sure you adjust for `np.random.choice` to account for replacement